Prevent screen capture and screen recording in an iOS app in swift
My use case
1 - By default I have to prevent screen capture and recording of my app.
2 - But also We have option in setting menu to disable this prevention.
I have written the code to achieve my first use case and it's working fine.
func disableScreenSharing(window: UIWindow) {
        let field = UITextField()
        
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: field.frame.self.width, height: field.frame.self.height))
        
        let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "whiteImage"))
        image.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        
        field.isSecureTextEntry = true
        
        window.addSubview(field)
        view.addSubview(image)
        
        window.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(field.layer)
        field.layer.sublayers?.last!.addSublayer(window.layer)
        
        field.leftView = view
        field.leftViewMode = .always
    }

But I'm not sure how to achieve the second use case to remove prevention the screen capture and recording.
You answers is highly appreciable.
I have to enable and disable screen capture and screen recording from the setting menu.
how to achieve this in swift

Could you add a bool to User Defaults to determine if it should be disabled or not?
Something like:
@AppStorage("disableScreenCapture") var disableScreenCapture: Bool = false

 Toggle("Disable Screen Recording", isOn: $disableScreenCapture)

Then in your function do an if check to see if dsiableScreenCapture is enabled or not.
Maybe even create a UserSettings or UserPrefrences class to manage all the settings across the app too.

thanks for you suggestion but my question is related to how remove or re enable the screen sharing? btw I found the solution. simple I have to toggle the textField.isSecureTextEntry = false.
